# Get my friends activities using redis (redis JOIN alternative)

Tags: database-design, redis, nosql

I want to improve performance of application by using redis. I successfully using it for caching and counters, and now trying to use it for searching for my friends activities.

We have 2 tables:

- activities (user, activity, timestamp)
- friends (user, friend)

I need to be able to get my friends activities sorted by timestamp. In sql it may look like:

```
SELECT act.activity, act.timestamp FROM activities act
JOIN friends fr ON fr.friend=act.user AND fr.user="{user}"
WHERE act.timestamp < {last}
ORDER BY act.timestamp DESC
LIMIT {limit}
```

UPD gist: https://gist.github.com/nanvel/8725b9c71c0040b0472b

UPD timing: https://gist.github.com/nanvel/8725b9c71c0040b0472b#file-timings-sqlite-vs-redis

My implementation with redis (consider, user can have thousands of friends and hundreds of activities):

```
import os.path
import sqlite3
import redis
import time
import uuid


class RedisSearch(object):

    @property
    def conn(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_conn'):
            return self._conn
        self._conn = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost')
        return self._conn

    def clean(self):
        for key in self.conn.keys('test:*'):
            self.conn.delete(key)

    def add_friend(self, user, friend):
        self.conn.sadd('test:friends:{user}'.format(user=user), friend)

    def add_activity(self, user, activity, timestamp):
        pipe = self.conn.pipeline()
        pipe.zadd('test:last_user_activity', timestamp, user)
        pipe.zadd('test:user_activities:{user}'.format(user=user), timestamp, activity)
        pipe.execute()

    def search(self, user, last, limit):
        tmp_key = 'text:tmp:{user}'.format(user=user)
        pipe = self.conn.pipeline(False)
        pipe.zinterstore(
            dest=tmp_key,
            keys=['test:last_user_activity', 'test:friends:{user}'.format(user=user)],
            aggregate='max')
        pipe.zrevrange(tmp_key, 0, -1)
        pipe.delete(tmp_key)
        users = pipe.execute()[1]
        if not users:
            return []
        user_keys = []
        for u in users:
            user_keys.append('test:user_activities:{user}'.format(user=u))
        pipe = self.conn.pipeline(False)
        pipe.zunionstore(dest=tmp_key, keys=user_keys, aggregate='max')
        pipe.zremrangebyscore(tmp_key, min=last, max=get_timestamp())
        pipe.zrevrange(tmp_key, 0, limit-1)
        pipe.delete(tmp_key)
        return pipe.execute()[2]


def get_timestamp():
    return int(time.time() * 1000000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_path = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'activities.sqlite3')
    con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    redis_search = RedisSearch()
    redis_search.clean()
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.executescript(u"""
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS activities;
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS friends;
            CREATE TABLE activities(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user VARCHAR(31), activity VARCHAR(31), timestamp INTEGER);
            CREATE TABLE friends(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user VARCHAR(31), friend VARCHAR(31));
        """)
        authors = []
        for i in xrange(100):
            # create 100 activities
            author = uuid.uuid4()
            authors.append(author)
            activity = uuid.uuid4()
            timestamp = get_timestamp()
            cur.executescript(u"""
                INSERT INTO activities(user, activity, timestamp) VALUES("{user}", "{activity}", {timestamp});
            """.format(user=author, activity=activity, timestamp=timestamp))
            redis_search.add_activity(user=author, activity=activity, timestamp=timestamp)
        user = uuid.uuid4()
        for i in xrange(100):
            # create friends
            friend = uuid.uuid4()
            cur.executescript(u"""
                INSERT INTO friends(user, friend) VALUES("{user}", "{friend}");
            """.format(user=user, friend=friend))
            redis_search.add_friend(user=user, friend=friend)
        # more friends
        for i in xrange(100):
            u = uuid.uuid4()
            f = uuid.uuid4()
            cur.executescript(u"""
                INSERT INTO friends(user, friend) VALUES("{user}", "{friend}");
            """.format(user=u, friend=f))
            redis_search.add_friend(user=u, friend=f)
        # add outhors to friends
        for i in xrange(20):
            cur.executescript(u"""
                INSERT INTO friends(user, friend) VALUES("{user}", "{friend}");
            """.format(user=user, friend=authors[i]))
            redis_search.add_friend(user=user, friend=authors[i])
        # select my friends activities
        last = get_timestamp()
        for i in xrange(2):
            print '--- page {n} ---'.format(n=i + 1)
            cur.execute(u"""
                SELECT act.activity, act.timestamp from activities act
                JOIN friends fr ON fr.friend=act.user AND fr.user="{user}"
                WHERE act.timestamp < {last}
                ORDER BY act.timestamp DESC
                LIMIT {limit}
            """.format(user=user, last=last, limit=10))
            new_last = last
            for r, timestamp in cur:
                print r
                new_last = timestamp
            print '---'
            for r in redis_search.search(user=user, last=last, limit=10):
                print r
            last = new_last
```

Thanks a lot for Your answers!

UPD: I rewrote search function with lua:

```
def search(self, user, last, limit):
    SCRIPT = """
    redis.call("ZINTERSTORE", "test:tmp:" .. ARGV[1], 2, "test:last_user_activity", "test:friends:" .. ARGV[1], "AGGREGATE", "MAX")
    local users = redis.call("ZREVRANGE", "test:tmp:" .. ARGV[1], 0, -1, "WITHSCORES")
    if users == nil then
        return {}
    end
    redis.call("DEL", "test:tmp:" .. ARGV[1])
    local counter = 0
    local lastval = users[1]
    for k, v in pairs(users) do
        if (counter % 2 == 0) then
            lastval = v
        else
            redis.call("ZUNIONSTORE", "test:tmp:" .. ARGV[1], 2, "test:tmp:" .. ARGV[1], "test:user_activities:" .. lastval, "AGGREGATE", "MAX")
            redis.call("ZREMRANGEBYSCORE", "test:tmp:" .. ARGV[1], ARGV[2], ARGV[3])
            if redis.call("ZCOUNT", "test:tmp:" .. ARGV[1], v, ARGV[2]) >= tonumber(ARGV[4]) then break end
        end
        counter = counter + 1
    end
    local users = redis.call("ZREVRANGE", "test:tmp:" .. ARGV[1], 0, ARGV[4] - 1)
    redis.call("DEL", "test:tmp:" .. ARGV[1])
    return users
    """
    return self.conn.eval(SCRIPT, 0, user, last, get_timestamp(), limit)
```

UPD 2016-05-19

I did it wrong, there are related links to the right solution:

- [How Instagram Feeds Work: Celery and RabbitMQ](http://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/04/how-instagram-feeds-work-celery-and-rabbitmq.html)
- [Stream-Framework](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework)
- [The Architecture Twitter Uses To Deal With 150M Active Users, 300K QPS, A 22 MB/S Firehose, And Send Tweets In Under 5 Seconds](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html)
- [Facebook’s Instagram: Making the Switch to Cassandra from Redis, a 75% ‘Insta’ Savings](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/interview/facebooks-instagram-making-the-switch-to-cassandra-from-redis-a-75-insta-savings/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your Lua script does. It seems it:

1. Copies all activities to a new redis key and sorts them by timestamp,
2. Deletes most of these copied activities,
3. Fetches the rest,
4. Deletes the key, created on first step, and containing this rest.

Here are my suggestons:

- Do you have a reason to create a new complete list of activities each time you need to display the last 10 or 20 to user?
- Why can't you keep it for some minutes and re-use it to display a next page?
- And why do you ask Redis server to delete items from sorted set if you're going to drop the key in the same Lua script?

If your application does not allow users to display an arbitrary activity page (I mean if user can only scroll down to see more), please consider using friend activity keys directly and saving the scan/iteration context. You can try the following:

- Get the same number of items (matching the page size) from each friend's activity set using ZRANGE/ZREVRANGE command,
- Return the items having the highest scores (timestamps);
- Positions of the last returned item for each activity list are your "iteration context",
- Save this context (say, in user's session) and use it to select data for the next activity page.

And maybe you don't need Redis for this task. You can use a database table to store the list activities to be displayed to user. You'll have to pre-populate it when user adds a friend and add an item for each friend's activity. Of course there are pros and cons for this solution and I can't suggest it ultimately. It's up to you to choose.

Hope this helps.